# File Type To Program Associations And File Location(Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file

In Windows if I have a program association set to invoke my program to open/edit a data file with a specific extension, how will my program - once invoked - know the path and filename of the data file? Preferably solutions using batch, C++, or C. -Tom

Comment: `the compiler is programmed with batch because it works well with string parsing and Windows.` Somehow I have big doubts about both parts of this sentence.

Comment: Before you go too far in that direction... `the compiler is programmed with batch because it works well with string parsing and Windows` You may want to reconsider that assumption. Windows batch files routinely choke on common ASCII characters like `><|&^%!` in various contexts, and have no built-in support for Unicode.

Comment: @TomBurris No worries Tom.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the command line arguments (i.e. `%1`, `%2`... for batch, `argv[1]`... for C++, C) - they should hold the path and name of the .gb file (or if there's no path, at least a name relative to the current working directory).

Comment: Those are for arguments explicitly passed on the command line, which the OP said nothing about. `argv[0]` or `%0` actually point to the executing app or batch, and in the latter case `%~dp0` is the drive+directory of the running batch - which may be closer to what the title suggests `Where Batch File Was Executed From`.

Comment: @dxiv The OP said nothing about them because the OP doesn't know they're the place to look.  `argv[0]` / `%0` will be the program he's stipulated to handle `.gb` files - my understanding is that he needs that program to know where the `.gb` file he's been asked to handle is located - that's why I suggest `%1` / `argv[1]` (and maybe more if there're multiple files).  Where the handling program is running is of no ostensible use: Windows will have found it through program association; it doesn't need to find itself.  Not possible to get any understanding of this question from the title alone.

Comment: I see that the OP just changed the title of the question, so +1 for your crystal ball.